# Where can a find Ubuntu minor releases change log?

Tags: release-management, changelog

Where can a see online Ubuntu minor releases change log / release log?

Google or search here did not help. I've only found the major release notes.

For instance, I want to see what minor releases have been made since the first 20.04 release and what was fixed.

Thanks